# Contact Form 7 change user role after submitting

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Okay I've been trying to make the following:

If current user role is SUBSCRIBER and contact form id "1234" has been successfully submitted, then change user role to EDITOR.

This is what I made so far, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'changerole_wpcf7' );

function changerole_wpcf7( $contact_form ) {
$user = wp_get_current_user();
     if ( ! empty( $user ) && in_array( "subscriber", (array) $user->roles ) && $contact_form->id() !== 1234 )
       return;
         $user->remove_role( "subscriber" );
         $user->add_role( "editor" );

    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright folks I finally made it work. I made some small changes to @rank code and also added `subscribers_only: true` to the "Additional Settings" tab in Contact Form 7.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'changerole_wpcf7' );

function changerole_wpcf7( $cf7 ) {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_id = $user->ID;
        $user_meta = get_userdata($user_id);
        $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;      
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        
        if ( $cf7->id() == 1234 ) {
          if($submission) {
            if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $user_roles ) ) {
                wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => 'editor' ) );
                
            }
        }
    } else { return; }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `return` terminates the execution of your function. So you will never get to the part where you remove and and add the role.

---

**Edit**: Try it with other hook "wpcf7_before_send_mail" and check if user is logged in. You can update the user role instead of remove and adding it.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'changerole_wpcf7' );

function changerole_wpcf7( $contact_form ) {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_id = $user->ID;
        $user_meta = get_userdata($user_id);
        $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;

        if ( $contact_form->id() == 1234 ) {
            if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $user_roles ) ) {
                wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => 'editor' ) );
            }
        }
    } else { return; }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately even with those fixes I still can't make it work

Comment: I edited my answer and did a way a little bit different to your code in the question.

Comment: this is the best answer but only missing to mention that is needed to be added "subscribers_only: true" to the "Additional Settings" tab. In addition "else { return; }" at the end of the function isn't necessary